# Fill whole db from scratch (with M:M relationships) with one SaveChanges() command

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My database is empty and in my C# application I need to fill it and use just one .SaveChanges() command - either everything will be saved, or nothing will be saved.

The problem I'm having is this:

I have 3 tables: Person, Class, PersonClass. Those are empty.

So, in C# code, via Entity model, I add a person {Id: 1, Name: John}.
Next, I want to add a relationship between John and some class, and after that I want to add the class. So, after I create John I do this:

```
John.Classes.Add(new Class
                        {
                            ClassId = 1
                        });
```

And after that i add Maths in the db.

AFTER that I SaveChanges(), and I get the Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint: Cannot insert duplicate key.

In my PersonClass table I have 2 columns - personId and classId. They are both primary keys and they are bot not auto-incremented properties.

Person has 2 columns: id and Name. Class has just one column - id. The ids are primary keys, but not auto-incrmeented.

Comment: Need to see your model definitions for Person and Class.

Comment: @KeithPayne I added that in the question. Pls see.

Comment: It is the EF models that are important for fixing this. The tables are an artifact of the models. What I am getting at is that you might be putting the cart before the horse by concentrating on the tables. For instance, in EF you do not define the xref table of a m:m relationship. EF does that for you. And if you work correctly in EF, then it also takes care of assigning foreign-key values at the time that you call `SaveChanges()`. With the code for the models posted, I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stick to "just one SaveChanges" if you want to enforce "either everything is saved or nothing is", you should split it into many saves but wrap them within the same transaction and only commit that transaction at the end.

The advantage is that if it fails, you'll have a better view of WHERE it failed (instead of doing it at the end and needing to dig deep into the exception to get a cryptic error).

For an example in EF6 or higher : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Comment: Good advice, but does not address the question. Perhaps this is better as a comment.

Comment: It does address the question, the question was about saving it all in one set of savechanges, it doesn't explain why he has an exception but no one can answer to that (and i'll edit to answer to that) untill he answered your question, no model, no good answer. But this is definately part of the answer and not just a comment as his issue is also a clear missunderstanding of the "all or nothing" nature of of a save.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau How do I do this?

Comment: @petko_stankoski If you are using EF6 or higher you can view a good starting documentation there : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Nope, I'm using EF5.

Comment: You can use transactions with earlier EF versions too, that article only covers EF6, this is a googling job that i leave to you